# How to keep circles inside the svg when updating data in bubble chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, circle-pack

I am trying to add interaction in the bubble chart and update data when clicking on the according button. But sth goes wrong when I click the button, the circles go out of the bound of the svg. I can't figure out how to fix it. Please help!

Here is the working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/87WLm3OmK1jRtcq8p96u?p=preview).(Try 2006,2007 or 2008)

```
function changebubble(i) {

d3.csv("count_s.csv", function(csvData) {

pack.value(function(d){var valuedata=[d.count2006, d.count2007, d.count2008];
return valuedata[i];});

var data = { name: "city", children: csvData };

var node = svg.data([data]).selectAll("circle")
  .data(pack.nodes);

var nodeEnter=node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node").attr("cx",0).attr("cy",0)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });


nodeEnter.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.city+ " : " +format(d.value); });


nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.city); });


 nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".3em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.city });

node.select("circle")
    .transition().duration(1000)
   .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.city); });

 node.transition().attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
     return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});

 node.select("text")
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("dy", ".3em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.city });

node.select("title")
.transition().duration(1000)
 .text(function(d) { return d.city+ " : " +format(d.value); });

node.exit().remove();

 });

 }

function updateBubble1() {changebubble(0);}
function updateBubble2() {changebubble(1);}
function updateBubble3() {changebubble(2);}

d3.select("#count2006").on("click",updateBubble1);
d3.select("#count2007").on("click",updateBubble2);
d3.select("#count2008").on("click",updateBubble3);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code on Plunker does not seem to reflect that which you've pasted above (it has no button interactions), can you update it as such?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! It is my first time using stack overflow and I thought I would receive an email whenever got a response. I updated the Plunk. Could you please check it again? Thanks very much!

Comment: I managed to keep the circles in place now, but the old circles don't exit. Could you please take a look at the bubble.js and help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your update function, to name a couple of big ones:

- The elements you are selecting (`var node = svg2.selectAll("circle")`) do not match the elements you are 'entering' (`var nodeEnter=node.enter().append("g")`).  This leads to problems when defining key functions and performing data joins
- You seem to be trying to rebind the data when transitioning existing elements (`node.select("circle").data(pack.nodes,function(d) {return d.city})`) This will cause problems -- the data is already bound to these elements and re-binding is un-necessary at this point.

I've made updates to your code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pYQTCOKWXoRM3ZE0HEt3?p=preview

Comment: Wow!It is truly helpful! Thanks so much for pointing out the problems and updating my code! I feel very grateful for your help! As a d3 beginner, I sometimes feel really frustrated to self-study all the stuff and debug the code. Thank you for being here for us!